# Promesas con node.js

Tags: nodejs, promesas

Hola tengo este problema con un codigo de node.js. La idea del codigo es que copie un archivo dentro del servidor, pero por alguna razón la informacion del alchivo no es transmidita como parametro a la siguiente promesa.
Aqui tienen el codigo espero puedan ayudarme:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs'),
      file = 'assets/Nombres.txt',
      newFile = 'assets/Nombres-copia.txt'

var Promesa1 = new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
    fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK, function (e){
        return (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no existe')) : resolve(true)
    })
}),
    Promesa2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    console.log( 'El archivo existe.')
    fs.readFile(file, (e, data)=>{
        (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no se ha leido.')):resolve(data)
        return data 
    })
}),
    Promesa3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        console.log('Data en promesa3: ', resolve)   
        console.log( 'El archivo se ha leido exitosmente.')
        fs.writeFile( newFile, resolve, (e)=>{
            return (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no pudo ser copiado.')) : resolve('El archivo fue copiado con exito.')
        })
})

Promesa1
    .then( (resolve, reject)=>{
        return Promesa2
    })
    .then( (resolve, reject)=>{
        return Promesa3
    })
    .then( (resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log(resolve)
    })
    .catch( (e)=>{
        console.log(e.message)
    })
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema es que estas usando mal los resolve y reject de las promesas dentro de los then, y ademas nunca pasas la data real que queres copiar de la promesa 2 a la promesa 3 sino que estas usando el resolve directo, el cual es código nativo de las promesas de javascript, te recomiendo hacer funciones que devuelvan promesas, y los resultados de cada una, pasarlas a la próxima promesa mediante parámetros, de esta forma funcionaria, espero te sirva:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs'),
    file = 'assets/Nombres.txt',
    newFile = 'assets/Nombres-copia.txt';

const promesa1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK, function (e){
        return (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no existe')) : resolve(true)
    })
});

const promesa2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log( 'El archivo existe.');
    fs.readFile(file, (e, data)=>{
        (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no se ha leido.')): resolve(data)
        return data 
    })
})

const promesa3 = fileForCopy => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log( 'El archivo se ha leido exitosmente.');
    fs.writeFile( newFile, fileForCopy, (e) => {
        return (e) ? reject(new Error('El archivo no pudo ser copiado.')) : resolve('El archivo fue copiado con exito.')
    })
});

promesa1()
    .then( response => {
        return promesa2();
    })
    .then( response => {
        return promesa3(response);
    })
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch( (e)=>{
        console.log(e.message)
    });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. 
Me sirvió mucho.